# list initialization of aggregates: when can it invoke copy constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, aggregate, language-lawyer, list-initialization

Consider the following code:

```
struct A {
  int x;
};

int main() {
  A a;
  A b{a};
}
```

Is this program well-formed at C++11 standard? In my copy of N3797 it says

> 8.5.4 List initialization `[dcl.init.list]`
>
> 3: List-initialization of an object or reference of type `T` is defined as follows:
>      - If `T` is an aggregate, aggregate initialization is performed (8.5.1).
>      - Otherwise, if `T` is a specialization of `std::initializer_list<E>`, ...
>      - Otherwise, if `T` is a class type, constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated and the best one is chosen using overload resolution. If a narrowing conversion is required to convert any of the types, the program is ill-formed.
>      - Otherwise, if the initializer list has a single element of type `E` and either `T` is not a reference type or it is reference-related to `E`, the object or reference is initialized from that element; if a narrowing conversion is required to convert the element to `T`, the program is ill-formed.
>      - Otherwise, if `T` is a reference type, a pr-value temporary of the type reference by `T` is copy-list-initialized or direct-list-initialized, depending on the kind of initialization for the reference, and the reference is bound to that temporary.
>      - Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements, the object is value-initialized.
>      - Otherwise, the program is ill-formed.

The point of the example is, the type is an aggregate, but list-initialization is supposed to invoke the copy constructor. On `gcc 4.8` and `gcc 4.9`, at C++11 standard, it fails:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:7:8: error: cannot convert ‘A’ to ‘int’ in initialization
   A b{a};
        ^
```

and says `A is not convertible to int` or similar, because aggregate initialization fails. On `gcc 5.4`, it works fine at C++11 standard.

On `clang` you get similar errors with `clang-3.5`, `3.6`, and it starts working at `clang-3.7`.

I understand that it is well-formed at C++14 standard, and that it was mentioned in a defect report [here](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1467).

However, what I don't understand is why this was considered a defect in the standard.

When the standard writes,

"If `X`, foo-initialization is performed. Otherwise, if `Y`, bar-initialization is performed, .... Otherwise, the program is ill-formed.",

doesn't this mean that if `X` holds, but foo-initialization cannot be performed, then we should check if `Y` holds, and then attempt bar-initialization?

This would make the example work, because when aggregate initialization fails, we don't match `std::initializer_list`, and the next condition we match is "`T` is a class type", and then we consider constructors.

Note that this *does* seem to be how it works in this modified example

```
struct A {
  int x;
};

int main() {
  A a;
  const A & ref;
  A b{ref};
}
```

All the same compilers treat this the same way as the earlier example, at C++11 and C++14 standards. But it seems that the modified wording from the CWG defect record doesn't apply to this case. It reads:

> If `T` is a class type and the initializer list has a single element of type `cv T` or a class type derived from `T`, the object is initialized from that element.

http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1467

But in the second code example, the initializer list technically contains `const T &`. So I don't see how it would work unless after aggregate initialization fails, we are supposed to attempt constructors.

Am I wrong? Is it not supposed to attempt constructors after aggregate initialization fails?

Here's a related example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct B {
  int x;

  operator int() const { return 2; }
};

int main() {
  B b{1};
  B c{b};
  std::cout << c.x << std::endl;
}
```

In `clang-3.6`, `gcc-4.8`, `gcc-4.9`, it prints `2`, and in `clang-3.7`, `gcc-5.0` it prints `1`.

Assuming I'm wrong, and at C++11 standard, list initialization of an aggregate is supposed to be aggregate initialization and nothing else, until the new wording in the defect report is introduced, is it a bug that this happens even when I select `-std=c++11` on the newer compilers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When the standard writes,
>
> "If `X`, foo-initialization is performed. Otherwise, if `Y`,
>   bar-initialization is performed, ...
>
> doesn't this mean that if `X` holds, but foo-initialization cannot be
>   performed, then we should check if `Y` holds, and then attempt
>   bar-initialization?

No.  If `X` holds we perform foo-initialization.  If that fails the program is ill-formed.

Comment: So what do you think about the `struct B` example? You think `gcc` and `clang` are using some C++14 feature that shouldn't be available in C++11 standard?

Comment: @ChrisBeck: I think they've decided that this was a clear defect in the C++11 standard, and they have implemented the fixed version.  I suspect the only reason this never got to "resolved" was that they have started doing C++ releases much faster, so rather than fixing defects in the old standards, they just fix it in the latest.

Answer (score 4):

> When the standard writes,
>
> "If X, foo-initialization is performed. Otherwise, if Y, bar-initialization is performed, .... Otherwise, the program is ill-formed.",
>
> doesn't this mean that if X holds, but foo-initialization cannot be performed, then we should check if Y holds, and then attempt bar-initialization?

No, it does not. Think of it like actual code:

```
T *p = ...;
if(p)
{
  p->Something();
}
else
{ ... }
```

`p` isn't NULL. That doesn't mean it's a valid pointer either. If `p` points to a destroyed object, `p->Something()` failing will not cause you to skip to the `else`. You had your chance to protect the call in the condition.

So you get undefined behavior.

The same goes here. If X, do A. That doesn't imply what happens if A fails; it tell you to do it. If it can't be done... you're screwed.

Comment: So you think in my example with `struct B`, `gcc-5` should behave the same as `gcc-4.8` and `gcc-4.9`, when `std=c++11`?

Comment: @ChrisBeck: That's a *different* question. That's a question of whether defect fixes should be retroactively applied to existing standards. And the answer to that one is, generally speaking, yes. That's what a defect report *is*; it's a *bug* in the standard. Bugs should be fixed, and you shouldn't have to say you're using the next version to get them, right?

Comment: I mean there is a difference between a bug in the implementation of the standard, and a defect in the wording of the standard. The former, yeah that should be resolved by a release incrementing only the patch-level, ideally. But if I say `std=c++11` I generally assume they are trying to implement N3797. Otherwise it means I can't really know what the compiler will try to do unless I read all the standards. Or I have to tell people "you can't use clang after version 3.6, or unfortunately it will compile but the intializations won't work like intended and you'll see 1 instead of 2"

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand what "defect reports" are in C++. Are defect reports, a problem with release X that we hope to address in next release, or do they essentially have bugfix releases of previously released standards? I thought that basically the C++11 standard doesn't change after it's published, and any defect reports are discussion items for C++14 etc.

Comment: @ChrisBeck: Defect reports are bug in the standard. The committee does not make bugfix releases of the whole standard, but they do make it clear when they've approved a defect report and exactly what the fix is in terms of wording.

Comment: I see. So on the defect report page, it says "Issues with DR, accepted, DRWP, and WP status are NOT part of the International Standard for C++. They are provided for informational purposes only, as an indication of the intent of the Committee." And when I ask the compiler for `--std=c++11`, it means, C++ as described in C++11 standard document, plus any defect reports which clarify the intent of the standards committee? Or something like this?

Comment: I guess it's extremely unlikely that this change would actually break a program designed for c++11 -- my example is pretty artificial, and an aggregate can't contain a copy of itself, so `A b{a};` just would have failed with the older compilers, unless these goofy implicit conversions are involved. Maybe if the aggregate contains a reference to itself or something, but that's also pretty artificial.